# Secure authentication choice (or service) for Mobile, Desktop and Web Apps

Tags: java, android, ios, node.js, authentication

We are developing a fast growing [YouTube live streaming app](http://www.cameleon.live) for several platforms, including both mobile and desktop OSs and Web.

At the moment we're based on a robust Node.js back-end and authentication powered by [Passport](http://passportjs.org), we should be happy with. However, maintenance, continuous development, controllers, tests, upgrades, security, etc. all take valuable time from our main focus. We love what we created but after one year must decide to shut it down and focus on what we do best.

Our options are:

1. switching to a very simple back-end that does nothing else but authentication and keeping basic user-data in a secure database. Something that is open-source and well supported, future proof (we're using Google, Facebook, GitHub and Twitter, optionally email-authentication for web, Mac, Win, iOS, Android and tvOS)
2. an affordable and fair SaaS that will do the job for us, without selling our clients; in this case some basic analytics would be awesome

2.1. [Google Identity Platform](https://developers.google.com/identity/) is a third option that would limit us to Google (last option)

I am sure, many of you have reached this point with projects that outgrew their original idea, architecture or purpose and this is why I am asking your help and opinion instead of risking a bad decision.

**App Authentication: SaaS vs Hosted solution** and if one or the other, **what are the best options?**

Thank you!